# ObjectiveC: Strange behavior when using NSString and __weak with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

First code and output:

```
NSString *text = @"Sunny";
__weak NSString *string0 = text.lowercaseString;
__weak NSString *string1;
string1 = text.lowercaseString;

NSLog(@"%@, %@", string0, string1);
```

Output:

```
(null), sunny
```

But after I move the declaration of `string1` above the `text`, output is different. Here is the code:

```
__weak NSString *string1;
NSString *text = @"Sunny";
__weak NSString *string0 = text.lowercaseString;
string1 = text.lowercaseString;

NSLog(@"%@, %@", string0, string1);
```

Output:

```
sunny, sunny
```

I am very confused with the different output:

- Why `string0` and `string1` is different in the first case?
- Why the output of second case is different with the first?

Comment: Even more strange is that first scheme gives correct output if you run by keeping a breakpoint and then execute line by line. However if you remove breakpoint it gives `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to figure out exactly when an object is released or a weak reference nulled can be challenging, and often doesn't really help understanding. Here are some reasons why you can see different results than you expect:

- `NSString`: It is best *never* to use this type when doing these kind of investigations. String literals are immortal, they are not collected, and you may have a string literal even when you don't expect one.
- *The auto-release pool*: The auto-release pool is really a hangover from the pre-ARC days, but it still exists and many methods return auto-released objects. What this means is many objects will live longer than you might expect, but not too long. However ARC has tricks and can remove objects from the auto-release pool early, so you might first think the object will live longer and then it doesn't...
- `weak` *references*: After the first two bullets you should guess that as you might have no real idea when an object gets released, if at all, then you might have no real idea when a `weak` reference gets nulled. Just think "soon enough".
- *Optimisation*: There is some leeway in optimisations the compiler can do which, while retaining the correct semantics of your program, may alter the lifetime of objects.

If you do want to run these kind of investigations then you will probably get further if (a) use your own class types, not anything from the libraries and (b) use `@autoreleasepool { ... }` blocks to limit the lifetimes of auto-released objects.

As an example, when I ran your code on the compiler I was using I did not get a `(null)`, however changing the first assignment to `string0 = text.lowercaseString.mutableCopy` did produce one... Figuring out why is left as an exercise...

Have an inquiring mind and explore, that is good, but be prepared for the non-obvious!

HTH